# How to apply toJson to instance of a case class using spray-json library

Tags: scala, akka, spray-json

Registration.scala

```
package model

import akka.actor.Actor
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

case class Registration(
  system: String, 
  identity: String)

object RegistrationProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val adsRegistrationFormat = jsonFormat2(Registration)
}
```

RegistrationService.scala

```
import akka.actor.{Props, ActorLogging, Actor}
import model.Registration

object RegistrationsService {
  case class PostRegistrationMessage(registration: Registration)

  def props(property: String) = Props(classOf[RegistrationsService], property)
}

class RegistrationsService(property: String) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import RegistrationsService._

  def receive = {
    case PostRegistrationMessage(registration) => {
      import model.RegistrationProtocol._

      val json = registration.toJson

    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why this is failing with compilation error "value toJson is not a member of model.Registration" and how to fix it. It if failing in the last line of the code above, which is "**val json = registration.toJson**"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import implicit operations provided by spray in RegistrationService.scala too

```
  import model.RegistrationProtocol._
  import spray.json._
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Thanks. I already imported RegistrationProtocol._, what's missing is 'import spray.json._'